# String copy in C using pointers doesn't show expected result

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I was trying to implement a string copy function using pointers as shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void copyStringPtr(char *from, char *to);

int main()
{
    char strSource[] = "A string to be copied.";
    char strDestination[50];

    copyStringPtr(strSource, strDestination);       // Doesn't work.

    return 0;
}

void copyStringPtr(char *src, char *dst)
{
    printf("The destination was\t:\t%s\n", dst);

//    for(; *src != '\0'; src++, dst++)
//        *dst = *src;

    while(*src)             //  The null character is equivalent to 0, so when '\0' is reached, the condition equals to 0 or false and loop is exited.
        *dst++ = *src++;

    *dst = '\0';

    printf("The source is\t\t:\t%s\n", src);
    printf("The destination is\t:\t%s\n\n", dst);
}
```

The expected output is :

```
The destination was :   
The source is       :   A string to be copied.
The destination is  :   A string to be copied.
```

But the output I'm getting is :

```
The destination was :   
The source is       :   
The destination is  :
```

As it can be seen, even the source doesn't seem to have the initialized value. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where do `src` and `dst` point right after the `while` loop?

Comment: I feel dumb. That comment in itself was the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to make a minor modification as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void copyStringPtr(char *from, char *to);

int main()
{
    char strSource[] = "A string to be copied.";
    char strDestination[50];

    copyStringPtr(strSource, strDestination);       // Doesn't work.

    printf("The source is\t\t:\t%s\n", strSource);
    printf("The destination is\t:\t%s\n\n", strDestination);

    return 0;
}

void copyStringPtr(char *src, char *dst)
{
    const char *srcOriginal = src;
    const char *dstOriginal = dst;

    printf("The destination was\t:\t%s\n", dstOriginal);

//    for(; *src != '\0'; src++, dst++)
//        *dst = *src;

    while(*src)             //  The null character is equivalent to 0, so when '\0' is reached, the condition equals to 0 or false and loop is exited.
        *dst++ = *src++;

    *dst = '\0';
}
```

And it worked just fine. As pointed out by @Jabberwocky in his comment, the pointers `*src` and `*dst` in `copyStringPtr` had moved to the end of the character string and was pointing to the NULL terminator.

Comment: `printf("The destination was\t:\t%s\n", dst);` is still a problem here, as `dst` points to uninitialized memory as pointed out by Blaze's answer.

Comment: I realize that now. I like both @Blaze's (uninitialized) and @Inian's (used `const`) answers. I'm editing this to combine both.

Answer (score 3):

One issue is that you're not initializing `char strDestination[50];`. Thus it doesn't represent a valid string and when you try to print it here:

```
printf("The destination was\t:\t%s\n", dst);
```

It is undefined behavior. You can initialize it like this:

```
char strDestination[50] = {'\0'};
```

This explicitly sets the first `char` to `'\0'`, making it a valid string. And the rest of the array is then default-initialized to `'\0'` anyway.

Also, after the `while` loop, your `src` and `dst` will point to the null terminator at the end of the strings, so when you print them, it prints nothing. Instead, keep a copy of the original pointers and print those instead:

```
void copyStringPtr(char *src, char *dst)
{
    char* srcOriginal = src;
    char* dstOriginal = dst;
    ...
    printf("The source is\t\t:\t%s\n", srcOriginal);
    printf("The destination is\t:\t%s\n\n", dstOriginal);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just take a backup of the original pointers before doing the increment. The reason you lose those pointers is, as part of the iteration in the `while` the start address of the string is lost and the `printf()` function does not know where the string starts. Since both the original pointers point at `\0` at the end of the loop, the `printf()` function does not see a an actual string to print up-to

You can even make these backup pointers `const` to disallow modifications made to them.

```
void copyStringPtr(char *src, char *dst)
{
    printf("The destination was\t:\t%s\n", dst);
    /*
     * backing up the original source/desination 
     * pointers
     */
    const char *b_src = src; const char *b_dst = dst;

    while(*src)             //  The null character is equivalent to 0, so when '\0' is reached, the condition equals to 0 or false and loop is exited.
        *dst++ = *src++;

    *dst = '\0';

    printf("The source is\t\t:\t%s\n", b_src);
    printf("The destination is\t:\t%s\n\n", b_dst);
}
```

Also as noted in Blaze's answer calling `printf()` on a uninitialized character array invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void copyStringPtr(char *from, char *to);

int main()
{
    char strSource[] = "A string to be copied.";
    char strDestination[50] = {0};

    copyStringPtr(strSource, strDestination);

    return 0;
}

void copyStringPtr(char *src, char *dst)
{
    char const *const dstOriginal = dst;

    if (!src || !dst){
        return;
    }

    printf("The source is\t\t:\t%s\n", src);

    while(src && *src)
        *dst++ = *src++;
    *dst = '\0';

    printf("The destination is\t:\t%s\n\n", dstOriginal );
}
```